# Visual Studio 2017 Compiler Error(s)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I just upgraded to VS2017 but right off the bat my project can no longer be built, as I am getting a bunch of strange compiler errors that didn't exist when I was using VS15.

Errors such as:

- `Syntax Error; value expected`
- `Invalid Expression Term '['`
- `Invalid Expression Term 'byte'`
- `Using the generic type requires 1 type arguments`

## Edit 1:

- Just created a small Console App and copied some of the code to it and the same compiler error(s) appeared

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Error
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Array array2D = null;
            if (array2D is Bgra <byte>[,])
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IColor { }

    public interface IColor<T> : IColor
        where T : struct
    { }

    public interface IColor2 : IColor { }

    public interface IColor2<T> : IColor2, IColor<T>
        where T : struct
    { }

    public interface IColor3 : IColor { }

    public interface IColor3<T> : IColor3, IColor<T>
        where T : struct
    { }

    public interface IColor4 : IColor { }

    public interface IColor4<T> : IColor4, IColor<T>
        where T : struct
    { }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Bgra<T> : IColor4<T>
        where T : struct
    {
        public Bgra(T b, T g, T r, T a)
        {
            B = b;
            G = g;
            R = r;
            A = a;
        }

        public T B;

        public T G;

        public T R;

        public T A;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"B: {B}, G: {G}, R: {R}, A: {A}";
        }

        public const int IDX_B = 0;

        public const int IDX_G = 1;

        public const int IDX_R = 2;

        public const int IDX_A = 3;
    }
}
```

Note that the exact same project compiles okay in VS15 and even VS13.

## Edit 2:

- VS15 <=> VS17
  [image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a small program?

Comment: Doesnt it specify a line of code the "syntax error" is supposed to be, if so whats the line?

Comment: @MatthewWatson #Edited

Comment: Try the as Keyword and check for null.
var tmp = array2D as Bgra<Byte>[,];
if (tmp != null)

(no VS2017 here, so I cant test)

Comment: Looks like a breaking change in the compiler, and perhaps a bug. I can reproduce the problem (and it definitely works OK in the previous compiler version!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson yea i have also added a picture side by side with both `VS15` and `VS17`

Comment: Could this be some new requirement for compiling your program in VS 2017?

Comment: @JDavila, as far as i know there is nothing wrong in my code and it compiled well in `VS13` and `VS15`

Comment: What message does the blue squiggle in VS2015 show? Could is be a warning in VS2015 but an error in VS 2017?

Comment: @DStanley nah it is just saying that the expression will be always false. Just because this is a snippet of my code copied to that project and `Array will always be null` so it must give a warning.

Comment: I'm assuming removing the space between Bgra and <byte> removes the error?

Comment: @tolanj It doesn't (and shouldn't)

Comment: I realise it _shouldn't_ but was given the error messages and the fact this seems to be a bug, seemed plausible it might.

Comment: I am curious if there is any update on this potential bug?  I ran into something similar in which VS2017 "recommends" I use pattern matching for:

`var entity = entry.Entity as ISelfReferencingTombstone<long, long?>;
if(entity != null)`

However, when using their recommendation I get compilation errors for missing ")" and missing ";"

VS2017 recommended rewrite:
`if (entry.Entity is ISelfReferencingTombstone<long, long?> entity)`

Far more succinct, but 100% less compilable :)

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, using `as` operator works as expected in Visual Studio 2017.

So you can use

```
var tmp = array2D as Bgra<Byte>[,]; 
if (tmp != null) { ... }
```

Also, `is` operator do works with simple array :

```
if (array2D is int[,]) { ... }
```

would also compile.

So it seems that the problematic case if when you have an array of generics. In fact, if you do something like

```
if (array2D is List<int>[,]) { ... }
```

you would get the compilation error.

Also the following code would compile

```
object something = null;
if (something is List<int>) { ... }
```

Thus, the only problematic case is when using an array of a generic type as the argument of the `is` operator.

As a side note, I would generally prefer using `as` operator to `is` operator since usually you need a variable in the target type anyway.

Comment: The same problem occurs with **Is-expressions with patterns** when using an array of generics... See also [What’s New in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

Comment: `as` operator works, yet there is no reason for `is` not to work as usual.

Comment: I agree that it should compile but I suspect that there were no unit test for that specific case requiring **(1)** arrays, **(2)** generics and **(3)** `is` operator. I recommend you to simplify you code to a minimal example and submit the problem to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

C#7 extends the `is` operator from pure type testing to what they call [Pattern Matching](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/future/docs/features/patterns.md).

The parser now seems to get confused by `is` followed by array-of-generic. I'd try with parens around the type, but I cannot test this solution

```
if (array2D is (Bgra<byte>[,]))
```

Comment: In that case, Is-expressions with patterns would also not works: `if (array2D is Bgra<byte>[,] localName)` would also not compile while generic or array alone properly works.